# Openstack-Install fails during juju bootstrapping

Tags: openstack-autopilot

I try to run a OpenStack installation based on "Openstack-Install" script.
I want to deploy a LAB enviroment. I setup a node as described [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

I added 6 nodes to the maas system. When I start the Openstack-Install script (I selected "Landscape Mode"), it terminates during the juju bootstrapping. Please find attached `commands.log`

```
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:53:21] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
Num items: 2, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:53:30] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:53:35] • cloudinstall.ui • (__init__.py, submit, 214)]
Callback on : OrderedDict([('Landscape OpenStack Autopilot', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Landscape OpenStack Autopilot' state=True>, 'Benefit from best practices in cloud building, and get up and running within minutes, all from an intuitive web UI.')), ('Multi', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi' state=False>, 'OpenStack installation utilizing MAAS.')), ('Single', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Single' state=False>, 'Fully containerized OpenStack installation on a single machine.'))])
[INFO  • 05-26 14:53:35] • cloudinstall.install • (install.py, do_install, 129)]
Performing a Landscape OpenStack Autopilot install
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:53:35] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
Num items: 4, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:55:53] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
Callback on : OrderedDict([('admin_email', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('admin_name', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_server', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_apikey', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:55:53] • cloudinstall.landscape_install • (landscape_install.py, _save_lds_creds, 81)]
Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:56:00] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, ssh_genkey, 819)]
ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG • 05-26 14:56:00] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 137)]
Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/bwarnsin/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap 
[DEBUG • 05-26 15:56:01] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 143)]
Problem during bootstrap: '{'status': 1, 'output': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\nWARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-0409d179-f4a5-11e4-805c-005056a75673/\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-0409d179-f4a5-11e4-805c-005056a75673/" is started but not deployed\n'}'
[DEBUG • 05-26 15:56:01] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
super().run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
self.installer.do_install()
File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[INFO  • 05-26 21:59:41] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 91)]
Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG • 05-26 21:59:41] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 97)]
Attempting to reset the terminal
```

So what I also can see, is that juju starts selcting a node from maas.
On that selcted node I saw following error message:

```
iscsistart:connect to X.X.X.X:3260 failed (Connect refused)
```

I checked already on my MAAS node (on which I started the Openstack-Install script) IP Tables-> Permit any any.

Comment: Are you able to run `juju bootstrap` outside of using the installer?

Comment: Yes I can, but the result on the node which will be bootstraped is the same. (iscsistart:.....failed (connect refused)

Comment: This could be an issue with the ephemeral images that maas uses, try re-importing your boot images

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the ssh key in your maas preferences is the same as in your public key?

Comment: Yes, I added my ssh public key via MAAS GUI

Answer (score 1):

Try this after cleaning up your failed installation:

Edit the file here:

> sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

Un-comment this line:

> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Now reboot MAAS and try the install again.

If that doesn't work try updating IPtables on MAAS with something like this:

> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 10.1.1.0/24 -m conntrack
>   --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
>
> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j
>   ACCEPT
>
> sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
>
> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>
> sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav

```
Edit /etc/rc.local and add the following lines before the "exit 0" line:
```

> iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav